# How to use a select with options instead two buttons for onClick event ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, grid, babeljs, jsx, use-state

I'm trying to simply change the use of two buttons for the select with two options, but the hook stop working.

```
export default function Home() {
const [className, setClassName] = useState("grid");
return (
  <>
<select className="catalogo-exibicao">
          <option
            value="grid"
          >
            em grid
          </option>
          <option value="list">em lista</option>
        </select>
        <button
          className="view-btn list-view"
          title="List View"
          onClick={() => setClassName("list")}
        >
          List View
        </button>
        <button
          className="view-btn list-view"
          title="Grid View"
          onClick={() => setClassName("grid")}
        >
          Grid View
        </button>

      <div
        className={className}
      >
    </>
);
}
```

In other file I have stylesheet specifying the difference for grid and list to change my div layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `setClassName` by passing the event object and extracting the selected value with event.target.value, on onChange of the option

```
const [className, setClassName] = useState("grid");
return (
  <>
<select className="catalogo-exibicao" onChange={e => setClassName(e.target.value)}>
          <option
            value="grid"
          >
            em grid
          </option>
          <option value="list">em lista</option>
        </select></>);
```